# Sqlitedataadapter works in one computer and not on another

Tags: c#, sqlite

I create a C sharp Desktop application in VS2013 using sqlite as a backend. When I needed lots of data from database at once, I loaded dataset to memory using classed like sqliteDataAdapter, datatable and dataset. Now the problem is that it completely works in my machine but not on my friends machine. I have windows 8 installed and friend's computer has windows 7 installed. I manually installed dotnet framework 4.5. While the program starts it doesn't get data from database using sqlitedataadapter. However SqliteDataReader seem to work.

Comment: VS2013 compiles to .net 4.5.1 by default. Also, I'm going to assume this is some centrally hosted database that is accessible outside of your pc?

Comment: Nope, its a standalone desktop application. Thats why I used light database (sqlite).

Comment: Do you have the database in the folder with the program, or at least the same relative position, on your friend's computer?

Comment: sqlite has single database file.I have MyDatabase.sqlite. The application can insert, update data into database. It can also read data using SqliteDataReader. Only thing that doesn't work is use of sqlitedataAdapter to access the whole table and load into memory. It returns null from such dataset. I dont want to change my program to only use SqliteDataadapter, at least I want to know why it doesn't work.